# Extension of isometry

Tags: linear-algebra, isometry, unitary-matrices

The original question is Here([In polar decomposition(A=RU) decomposition, How to extend Isometry into whole complex Euclidean space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3933004/in-polar-decompositiona-ru-decomposition-how-to-extend-isometry-into-whole-co))

But I make brief conditions that we need.

Let $X$ is complex Euclidean space and $A$ is linear mapping of $X$

Conditions

i) $A$ is not invertible,

ii) $AA^*=R^2$ where $AA^*$, $R$ is both nonnegative self-adjoint mapping

iii) $\parallel Rx\parallel = \parallel A^*x\parallel$ for any $x\in X$

iv) If $Rx=Ry$, $A^*x=A^*y$

For any $u$ in the range of $R$, $u=Rx$, we can define $Vu$ as $A^*x$

By upper condition, $V$ is isometry mapping of $Range(R)$ to $Range(A^*)$

---Here, I can't extend $V$ to whole space, $X$

I tried with following steps.

For any $x\in X$, $x$ can be decomposed by $x=u+v$ where $u\in Range(R), (u,v)=0$

Let $u=Ra$ for some $a$.

Then, $\parallel Vx\parallel = \parallel A^*a+Vv\parallel$

To make $V$ as unitary $\parallel Vv\parallel$ should be $\parallel v\parallel$

Also, $Vv$ must orthogonal with $Range(A^*)$

But I can't how to define this $Vv$ so that we can make sure existence of mapping $V$ which is unitary.

Comment: Why is it $U$ in the original title and then $V$ in your proof. Is it the same operator?

Comment: Actually, if $V$ is unitary, from definition of $V$, $A^*=VR$, so $A=RV^*$, so in this case, $V^*=U$ which is unitary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has $\ker(R) = \ker(A^*)$, hence $ran(R) = ran(R^*) = \ker(R)^\perp = \ker(A^*)^\perp$. It follows that the space $E$ is the orthogonal direct sum
\begin{equation}
E = \ker(A^*)^\perp \perp \ker(A^*)=ran(R)\perp \ker(A^*)
\end{equation}
You already defined $V$ on $ran(R)$, it remains to define it on $\ker(A^*)$. As $V$ sends $ran(R)$ onto $ran(A^*)=\ker(A)^\perp$ and you want a unitary operator, you need to send $\ker(A^*)$ to $\ker(A)$. Take any linear isometry
\begin{equation}
\varphi: \ker(A^*)\to\ker(A)
\end{equation}
and define $V x = \varphi(x)$ for all $x\in\ker(A^*)$. This extension of $V$ should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much. Since I learned linear algebra 3-4years ago, I'm not used to it.
Luckily, I think I understand your answer. Thank you again.